# Soundcloud Embed: Uncaught TypeError: Layer must be a document node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soundcloud

I have a Rails app that uses embedded soundcloud players.  The player is loaded in an iframe which includes a basic rails view containing the html used to load the player:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=<%= @id %>&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

Every now and then, when loading the site, the player fails to render and we get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Layer must be a document node

d          @ widget-6dc4a288.js:21
```

We also tried replacing the raw html with js code from the sc sdk, but still experienced the same error:

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: "<%= SECRET_KEY %>"
  });
  SC.oEmbed("<%= @id %>", {auto_play: true, height: 300}, function(oembed){
    document.getElementById('video-container').innerHTML = oembed.html;
  });
</script>
```

Does anyone know the source of this error?  It seems to occur about 1/4 times we try to render the sc player.